# Importing tweenMax into javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

im trying to  import TweenMax into my html, but i cant find what im doing wrong... I´ve done everything they say in their website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/PaginaFinal.css">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
```

Here im make the init;

```
<body onload="init()" onclick="pointerDefault(event)">

    <input type="text" id="search" name="procurarPalavra" onkeypress="premirEnter(event)">
    <img src="search.png" alt="Smiley face" id="ok" onclick="enviarPalavra(event)" >
    <img src="info.png" id="help">

<footer id="myFooter">

</footer>
```

The script goes here

```
    function init() {
        var search = document.getElementById("ok");
        var text = document.getElementById("search");
        var help = document.getElementById("help");
        search.hover(function () {
            TweenMax.to(this, .35, {width: "80", height: "80"})
        }, function () {
            TweenMax.to(this, .5, {width: "50", height: "50"})
        })

        text.hover(function () {
            TweenMax.to(this, .35, {width: "80", height: "80"})
        }, function () {
            TweenMax.to(this, .5, {width: "50", height: "50"})
        })

        help.hover(function () {
            TweenMax.to(this, .35, {width: "100", height: "100"})
        }, function () {
            TweenMax.to(this, .5, {width: "70", height: "70"})
        })   
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's happening? any errors in you console? how are you calling the `init()` function? do you have a `ok` id on a element?

Comment: Is your script placed above or below the TweenMax scripts? If it's above them, it should be placed below them instead.

Comment: @user3185775: hey, did my suggestion work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that you are expecting [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) of jQuery to work here but I do not see any jQuery imported. I could be wrong.

After loading jQuery, you could either wrap your `search` and other variables into a jQuery object e.g. `$(search)` or you could use jQuery to get them in the first place e.g. `var search = $('#ok');` instead of `var search = document.getElementById('ok');`.

Or, if you are looking to avoid jQuery, you could listen to `mouseover` and `mouseout` events using `addEventListener` method.